# How to count each characters inside the Parenthesis

Tags: php, string, count, output, character

Count each character in each box from the string example

```
   $str = 'man[big man]boy[big]guy[badforreal] and others';
```

**Expected Result:**

> you have 6 characters for (man)
>
> you have 3 characters for (boy)
>
> you have 10 characters for (guy)

Can I really achieve this in PHP?

Comment: Does it have to be solved in PHP?

Comment: have you tried to write some code?

Comment: @Basillicum
yes thanks if i understand you

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest
am so sorry i 0 idea on about php strings i just wana achieve and learn in my case

Comment: Add the code what you have tried with details of errors if you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
$array = explode("]", $str);
foreach ($array as $string){
    if( strpos($string, '[') !== false ){
        $strLabel = strstr($string, '[', true);
        $newStr .= "you have " . strlen(str_replace(["["," "], "", strstr($string, '['))) ." characters for (" . $strLabel .")<br/>";
    }
}
echo $newStr;
```

expected output

```
you have 6 characters for (man)
you have 3 characters for (boy)
you have 10 characters for (guy)
```

Answer (score 2):

Extended `preg_match_all` solution:

```
$str = 'man[big man]boy[big]guy[badforreal] and others';
preg_match_all('/([^\s\[\]]+)\[([^\[\]]+)\]/', $str, $matches);

if (isset($matches[1])) {
    foreach ($matches[1] as $k => $m) {
        printf("%s characters for (%s)\n", strlen(str_replace(" ", "", $matches[2][$k])), $m);
    }
}
```

The output:

```
6 characters for (man)
3 characters for (boy)
10 characters for (guy)
```